# SQL Rolling 13 months in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying the below query to get the last 13 rolling months from a certain table. I keep getting the error 'expected something between the where keyword and the year keyword'. Seems like it's something basic but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried putting parentheses too but it still gives me an error.

```
select  count(*)
from t
where year(creat_dt) * 100 + month(creat_dt) BETWEEN trunc(add_months(current_date,-13),'MM') AND last_day(current_date,'MM'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing an integer to a date.  How about just using dates?  If you have no future data, then this should be sufficient:

```
select  count(*)
from t
where creat_dt >=  trunc(add_months(current_date, -13), 'MM')
```